# Gettings C7621 when trying to use C++ 20 modules

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, c++-modules

I'm following this example of how to write modules in c++ 20: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170 and I continue getting an error C7621 "module partition 'XXX' for module unit 'XXX' was not found.

Following the example I've created the next ixx *primary module interface:

```
export module Chapter01;

export import :Question01;
```

I've then added the ixx module partition file:

```
export module Chapter01:Question01;

import <iostream>;
import <set>;

using namespace std;

export bool IsUnique(const std::string& str);
```

And the cpp implementation file:

```
module Chapter01:Question01;

import <iostream>;
import <set>;

using namespace std;

bool IsUnique(const std::string& str)
{
    set<char> charset = set<char>();

    for (const char c : str)
    {
        if (charset. Contains(c))
        {
            return false;
        }

        charset. Insert(c);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And I keep getting a C7621: **module partition 'Question01' for module unit 'Chapter01' was not found**

Looking at the example over and over again I can't seem to find the difference.

Removing the cpp file entirely and putting the implementation in the ixx file fixes the issue, but I would still like to understand why the separation doesn't work.

P.S. What is the best practice when working with modules? To separate the ixx and cpp files or to just include ixx files?

Comment: Please do not post images of code but copy the code as (copyable) text in the post itself.

Comment: Yes this is in VS22, adding the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you're using is incorrect. It suggests that you can have an implementation partition and interface partition that use the same partition name in the same module.

This is not allowed. All partitions within the same module must have *different* partition names.

Furthermore, the only reason to have an implementation *partition* is if you want some other module unit to be able to import that partition. Most implementation partitions don't need to be imported. So your implementation unit should just use `module Chapter01;`, and it will automatically import the `Chapter01` module.

Comment: Changing `module Chapter01:Question01;' to 'module Chapter01;' in the cpp file does seem to solve the issue.
But I still don't understand the issue then, or what files here had the same names, all files are named differently and all modules seem to have proper names, it would be great if you could explain that.

Also my intention is to indeed import this module and reuse it in a different project, and after the cpp change that doesn't work. Before that a unit test project I had could use that module, but now it fails on 'C3861' "'IsUnique': identifier not found".

Comment: "*it would be great if you could explain that*" I don't know what more I can say. Filenames *don't matter*; module names matter. "*Also my intention is to indeed import this module and reuse it in a different project*" The module itself or the specific *partition* unit that implements that function? Because those aren't the same thing.

Comment: The specific partition unit

Comment: @AntonVasserman: Well, you can't include a module partition from "a different project". That's the *entire point* of partition units; they can only be imported to a file that is part of the module they are a partition of. They are *inherently* private to a module. If you want to have a section of a module that you can import into other modules, what you want is a separate module.

Comment: Also, you don't need to break modules into tiny pieces. There is no reason why this "different project" couldn't just import `Chapter01` in its entirety and use from it which parts it wants. With inclusion, the more you include the slower compilation gets. Importing doesn't do that; that's one of the main points of the feature.

Comment: So just making sure I follow up:
1. I can't reference a different project and use specific partition units from it, only the project containing the module interface can use different partitions. Correct?
2. It is better to not break into different partitions and instead have a single module with my code it in so both I could consume it in a different project and it also improves compilation speed?

Comment: @AntonVasserman: "Project" is not a thing in C++; that's a build system concept. C++ cares about modules. A module partition can only be included by other units of the same module. Typically, a single module is built entirely within a "project". It might be possible to have some part of a module in a different "project" from the rest of it, but I doubt most build systems or compilers would be too happy with that. Furthermore, a file cannot be part of multiple modules, so any particular file can only import partitions from a *single* module.

Comment: It may be you were using an version of VS that was having issues. The code above is fine and compile fine with VS 17.8 Preview 3. I believe the comment by Nicol Bolas is wrong. It is perfectly fine to have an interface partition and a implementation of that interface in separate files. In fact you can have as many "cpp" implementation files implementing a given "ixx" module interface as you like. I use this as a module migration strategy in my code base all the time

Comment: @goneskiing: "*I believe the comment by Nicol Bolas is wrong. It is perfectly fine to have an interface partition and a implementation of that interface in separate files.*" I never said that you couldn't do that. What I said is that implementations can't be part of a different *module* (or outside of a "project").